# How are cards awarded on defeating a player in risk?

Tags: risk

I'm playing Risk, the Hasbro game on my iPad.

How are cards awarded once someone eliminates a single player? Sometimes it's 2, sometimes it's 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible the iPad version is using different rules, but [the official rules for the classic Risk Game](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/risk.pdf) are as follows:

> **Eliminating  an  opponent.**
>
> If  during  your  turn  you  eliminate  an
>   opponent  by  defeating  his  or  her  last  army  on  the  game  board,  you  win  any
>   RISK  cards  that  player  has  collected.

So you get all of the cards that the opponent had on hand. This will never be more than 6 cards (which is only possible if you somehow defeated a player who had just defeated another player on their turn). It does occur BEFORE drawing a RISK card from conquering a territory this turn, as your turn hasn't ended yet.

There are two highly-relevant bullet points with regards to this:

1. If you gain enough risk cards to cause you to have 6 or more cards on hand as a direct result of defeating an opponent, you MUST trade the cards in immediately for reinforcements so that you have 5 or fewer cards.
2. If you have 5 cards as a result of defeating an opponent and then your additional card from conquering a territory puts you at 6 cards, you trade at the start of your *NEXT* turn.

Comment: This answer is generally good, but is version dependant. Note that other versions state that you must trade in if eliminating another player gives you **5** or more cards, to make it consistent with the normal rule for trading in if you have 5 at the start of your turn. See [this excellent answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/25317/11743) on another question.

Comment: Yeah that's what happens in the hasbro game